# Send progress data from a long running async function on a Node Express Server to a react client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to be able to send some kind of progress data from a long running async function running on a node express server when a client requests for the data and waits for its completion.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    // Send data to client 
   (async () => {
      await someFunc();
   })();

})
```

Assuming ***someFunc()*** is responsible to return the progress data and the final response to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't do that since the first response will end the HTTP request (end the connection).
What you looking for is WebSocket, with WebSocket you can keep pushing data to the client since it maintains the connection

check https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

Comment: Exactly, hence the help required. Thank you for the reference. I will go through it. You're awesome.